# While printing statements to file, through sys.stdout=<log_file>, why does exceptions get printed on screen?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to redirect my print statements to log. My code:

```
   log_file=open(<log_file_path>, 'a')
   sys.stdout=log_file
```

Still exceptions raised, and printed, as:

```
   except Exception as e:
          print(e)
```

are getting printed on screen. Only print statements within try, and finally, are being printed to log file. How can I print the exceptions as well, to log file?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a single entry point. To do that, you need to use the `if __name__ == '__main__':` construct and call a `main` function (or whatever name you want).

For instance:

```py
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import print_function

import sys


def main():
    raise Exception("bad luck")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_file_path = "file.log"
    log_file = open(log_file_path, 'a')
    sys.stdout = log_file
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```

But, this is not a good practice, because you are changing the `sys.stout` global variable. This is ugly.

If you want to redirect you exceptions to a file, you can do:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_file_path = "file.log"
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as exc:
        with open(log_file_path, 'a') as f:
            print(exc, file=f)
```

Another good practice is to use the Python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.
Instead of printing, you use a logger.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```py
# coding: utf-8
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():
    LOG.info("Starting main()...")
    raise Exception("bad luck")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_file_path = "file.log"
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename=log_file_path, filemode='a')
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as exc:
        LOG.error(str(exc))
        raise SystemExit()
```

Explanation:

- in each module (Python file), you define a global variable named `LOG`.
- whenever you need to report a message, you use `LOG.info`, `LOG.debug`, `LOG.warning`…
- Your main error handler intercept any `Exception` and log with `LOG.error` (or `log.FATAL`).
- `raise SystemExit()` is here to return an non-nul exit code to the shell/bash/bat.